# Can I Wrap the Action URL in document.forms[0].action="" with pageTracker._getLinkerUrl?

Tags: javascript, forms, function, google-analytics, cross-domain

I have a web form that does not call an action, but when submitted gets sent to a Javascript function, which in essence, pushes the information to a 3rd party booking engine, and I want to pass the cookies along.  Basically the form gets sent to:

```
<a href="javascript:sendToCBE();"><img src="#"></a>
```

The sendToCBE function is as follows:

```
function sendToCBE(){
if (validateForm()){
    setHidden();
    document.forms[0].target="_blank";
    document.forms[0].action="http://partners.kcdataservices.com/resort/custom/buildMyOwn.jsp";
    document.forms[0].submit();
```

Is it possible to change this to

```
function sendToCBE(){
if (validateForm()){
    setHidden();
    document.forms[0].target="_blank";
    document.forms[0].action="pageTracker._getLinkerUrl(http://partners.kcdataservices.com/resort/custom/buildMyOwn.jsp)";
    document.forms[0].submit();
```

In order to have cross domain tracking and pass along the cookies so new ones are not set by the 3rd party booking engine? Is there a better (or simpler) way to do this that I have not found yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this snippet. Make sure to put GA related code inside a try catch so if it's not setup on the site the form still works.

```
function sendToCBE(){
  var action = "http://partners.kcdataservices.com/resort/custom/buildMyOwn.jsp";
  try{
    var tracker = _gat._getTrackers()[0];
    action = tracker._getLinkerUrl(action);
  }catch(e){
    // _gat doesnt exist or there is no tracker setup. Just ignore it and continue
  }
  if (validateForm()){
    setHidden();
    document.forms[0].target = "_blank";
    document.forms[0].action = action;
    document.forms[0].submit(); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I tested that out and it definitely worked.  I figured I had to somehow manipulate that part of the code, just wasn't sure how.

I am running into a second issue however.  Based on the items selected within the form, it is possible that the user is redirected to a third URL.  The redirect is not passing along any cookie information.  Can I use the same coding on the redirect page - or a variation of?

There is:
`function submitMe() {
 document.forms[0].submit();
}`

but also:
`<FORM method="post" onsubmit="pageTracker._linkByPost(this)" action="https://gc.synxis.com/rez.aspx?chain=`

Comment: that code doesn't seem right. You shouldn;t pass `this` to _linkByPost instead you should pass it the action attribute. maybe `this.action` works. Anyway I don;t see any redirect here, so I'm not sure I understand your question. Maybe it's better to post a new question on SO and put the link here, since it's a different issue.

Comment: I might try that.  The redirect is actually coming from that action I think (this happens automatically).  The above coding is on partners.kcdata.com (domain1) and is being sent to gc.synxis.com in the action (domain2) - if that makes sense.  Just to be clear (and I may have to post a new questions), it should look like
`onsubmit="pageTracker.linByPost(this.action)" action="https://gc.synxis.com"` ? Or am I mistaken?